# How to download Bing Static Map in Linux

Tags: linux, curl, bing-maps

I'm trying to download the static map using Bing Maps API. It works when I load the URL from Chrome, but when I tried to curl to wget from Linux, I got Auth Failed error.

The URL are identical but for some reason Bing is blocking calls from Linux?

Here's the commands I tried:

```
wget -O map.png http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Imagery/Map/Road/...
curl -O map.png http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Imagery/Map/Road/...
```

Error:

```
Resolving dev.virtualearth.net (dev.virtualearth.net)... 131.253.14.8
Connecting to dev.virtualearth.net (dev.virtualearth.net)|131.253.14.8|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized

Username/Password Authentication Failed.
--2016-10-24 15:42:30--  http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Imagery/Map/Road/.../12?mapSize=340,500
Reusing existing connection to dev.virtualearth.net:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized

Username/Password Authentication Failed.
```

I'm not sure if it has anything to do with Key Type, I've tried several from Public Website to Dev/Test but still didn't work.

Comment: Worth noting that it is against the terms of use of Bing Maps to store the map images. You can request and view them, but they can't be saved to the file system or a database for use later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url needs to be wrapped (because of `&` symbol in query string that needs to be escaped) with quotes:

```
wget 'http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Imagery/Map/Road/...'
```

**Examples**

Via `wget`:

```
wget -O map.jpg 'http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Imagery/Map/Road/Bellevue%20Washington?mapLayer=TrafficFlow&key=<key>'
```

Via curl:

```
curl -o map.jpg 'http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Imagery/Map/Road/Bellevue%20Washington?mapLayer=TrafficFlow&key=<key>'
```

> Have been verified under Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: How could I miss something that's so simple, anyway thx for the answer